# Fredhopper | Published XML is not being copied from UNIVERSE to incoming folder of IndexSever | Tridion2013SP1

Tags: smarttarget

I am implementing SmartTarget with Tridion2013SP1. When i publish any component it is successfully published in my CategoryFolder in FH i.e(C:\Fredhopper\SmartTarget\data\fas-xml-incremental\catalog01) but it is not going to incoming folder of my Index server i.e.(C:\Fredhopper\data\instances\SmartTarget\data\xml\incoming\batch).

I have also tried to run

```
bin\run-etl-job STJob.kjb "-DINSTANCE=SmartTarget" "-DTRIGGER=load-data" "-DUNIVERSE=catalog01" "-DEXECUTIONPATH=<BASE_DIRECTORY>/data/instances/SmartTarget/custom/"
```

command.It executes successfully but no changes are made. After that i moved Component XML from UNIVERSE To IncomingFolder of Index Server. It successfully moves to Processed items' folder.
I suspect Kettle job is not properly working. If anyone can please suggest if there is a way to configure KettleJob(STJob.kjb)?

Comment: I am using   fredhopper-7.5-revision-15.zip version of Fredhopper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your STJob is not working. It may be because of wrong version of Fredhopper installation.

Comment: Thanks Mukesh. I have now installed  fredhopper-7.5-revision-13.zip and its working now.